# How to get the final address to the PDF file stored by PrintManager.print

Tags: java, android, pdf

**=== Edited ===**

I create a report using html file and moustache. After that I load it in a WebView and use the PrintManage and PrintDocumentAdaptor to preview the report. Then user can store the file as a PDF **by changing from printer to PDF and press save**. This opens the file manager where you can choose where to store the file. After this I want to attach the created file to an email.

In the following snippet I can detect when the file is stored using onFinsih(), but I cannot find where it is stored.

```
public class PrintDocumentAdapterWrapper extends PrintDocumentAdapter {
    private PrintDocumentAdapter delegate;
    private String jobName;
    private WebView wv;

    public PrintDocumentAdapterWrapper(WebView wv,String jobName) {
        super();
        this.wv = wv;
        this.jobName = jobName;
        delegate = wv.createPrintDocumentAdapter(jobName);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayout(PrintAttributes printAttributes, PrintAttributes printAttributes1, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback layoutResultCallback, Bundle bundle) {
        this.delegate.onLayout(printAttributes, printAttributes1, cancellationSignal, layoutResultCallback, bundle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWrite(PageRange[] pageRanges, ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback writeResultCallback) {
        this.delegate.onWrite(pageRanges, parcelFileDescriptor, cancellationSignal, writeResultCallback);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        delegate.onFinish();
    while (!pj.isCompleted() && !pj.isCancelled() ){
            System.out.println("Print job is finished: " + pj.isCompleted() + "; canceled: " + pj.isCancelled());
        }
        if(pj.isCompleted()) {
            System.out.println("Print job is finished: " + pj.isCompleted() + "; canceled: " + pj.isCancelled());
            System.out.println("File is stored in this address: " + ADDRESS???!!!!!);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get the final address where the PDF file is stored? I need that to attache the file to an email programmatically after saving the file.

**========= EDIT ==========**

onFinish() does not catch the end of Print Job so I added some basic code to wait until the print job is either finished or canceled

Comment: What are you doing in `onWrite()` of the delegate? How are you using the `parcelFileDescriptor`?

Comment: @Zoso :I don't know how to use that to get the address!!

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Well, the unfortunate answer is "no", you can't. Why? Because the current code doesn't have any way to return that to the app(which is an oversight IMHO). To understand why, it would be worthwhile to understand some basic steps in the entire printing workflow.

### The How and the Why

***NOTE:*** The following answer assumes usage of the usual default print service provided by the system i.e. `com.android.printspooler` package.

When the `PrintManager` is requested to print, this request is sent to the `PrintManagerService`. This service internally launches the `PrintActivity` that is seen on the screen.

[image: PrintActivity]

It is this `PrintActivity` that in turn launches the Document Picker `PickActivity` which actually asks for the location to save this file to after the print attributes are selected/changed from the `PrintACtivity`.

[image: PickActivity]

This `PrintActivity` on finishing, returns the [`URI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri) of the actual file written to. This `URI` isn't passed back to the app in any of the callbacks or isn't queryable via the `PrintJob` class.

What about the ParcelFileDescriptor?
That, unfortunately, isn't a regular file and thus really isn't of much use for this current discourse. That can be determined by invoking [`getStatSize()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor#getStatSize()) on the `ParcelFileDescriptor` which returns -1 and as per the documentations means

> Returns -1 if the fd is not a file.

In reality, it is the *writing end* of the pipe obtained via [`createPipe()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor#createPipe()) and the actual PDF content that is to be printed is supposed to be written to it. Here's some sample code to illustrate how to write to it

```
FileOutputStream op = new FileOutputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());

//Create the PDF document
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

// create a page description
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(100, 100, 1).create();

// start a page
PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

//Draw on the PDF content to the page

// finish the page
document.finishPage(page);
// write the document content
try {
    document.writeTo(op);
    op.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// close the document
document.close();
```

### Extra

There's one file that the printing framework uses from which the final file is created and this remains cached in the files of the `com.android.printspooler` system package (the same one that hosts the `PrintActivity` above) till the printing process isn't over. This file is created as soon as the printing process is started i.e. the callback to `start()` is received in the `PrintDocumentAdapter` implementation. One can check this via command-line using (assuming yours is the only app crating print requests)

```
adb shell dumpsys print|grep print_job_files
```

This is the file that all the writes to the `parcelFileDescriptor` are written to. When the app reaches the `PickActivity` page, one can always pull this file from the files of the `com.android.printspooler` package (requires `adb root`).

```
adb pull /data/user/0/com.android.printspooler/files
```

[Note `/data/user/0/` is just the output of [`context.getFilesDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getFilesDir())]

This is the exact file that's written to the location chosen by the user via the `PickActivity`. If your setup allows you to perform (***very unportable***) machinations of extracting this cached file, you can always read in the file and access it. But for a general app off the PlayStore, this isn't possible at the present to my knowledge.

Comment: So it is not possible to get the file from the print job! Using the PdfDocument to create a file in memory to attach could be a solution but where do I have access to the content without using the cached file?

Comment: @msc87 Best bet would be to create an internal copy of the PDF document yourself and just use that in the mail attachment since your app is the one that's actually creating the PDF content.

Comment: I tried to that today but there is no good solution for converting an HTML-formatted string to a pdf. I read many posts in SO and used 'com.itextpdf:html2pdf' for converting but its result is bad. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @msc87 I missed your earlier message. Can't you draw your View (WebView?) to the PDF by using the [`getCanvas()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.Page?hl=en#getCanvas()) API?

Comment: I tried that but the pdf is one empty page. Plus, I don't know the number of pages as the report is built dynamically!!!

Comment: If you mean the ParcelFileDescriptor, returned by the PrintJob.getDocument().getData(), your assumption is wrong. Yes, it's not a regular file, so you can't do whatever you want with it, but you can read it sequentially from the AutoCloseInputStream, created from this descriptor.

Comment: @Ganster41 and how does that help in obtaining the `URI` of the written file? Obviously `ParcelFileDescriptor` can be read/written to by creating streams from them (my code snippet shows that). I don't quite understand the point you're trying to make here.

Comment: It doesn't. I was just confused why you demonstrated how to write into the descriptor, which is pretty much useless for the OP when he can actually read from there, and save the own copy of the printing PDF file.

Comment: Now I can save my own PDF in onWriteFinished and using that I can directly attach it to an email.